# Visual Studio Code: Clicking on blank line disrespects indentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

I want to start using VS code but this one issue is driving me insane.

The normal behavior I am expecting is that when I am typing and pressing Enter at the end of a line, the new line is  created and indented as expected, following the current scope's indentation:

[image]

My problem is, when I have inserted 2 newlines (pressed enter twice), or clicked on any empty line, the cursor always jumps back to the beginning and does not adhere to the indentation. In the image below I added a new line and then clicked on line 88 and the cursor automatically moved to the start of the line.

[image]

The only setting and suggestions I could find was to change the following setting:
`"editor.autoIndent": "full"`. This however did nothing to help with this issue.

The only extensions installed are C#, Razor/Blazor and Code Spell Checker.

Is there any other setting that can be set to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode automatically clears the indent of empty lines as you can see on the image below:

[image]

There is an issue open on VSCode's GitHub (see [#1](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1980)), and requests for a Visual Studio-like solution for it (see [#2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960)), but it doesn't seem like something that will be implemented soon.